# webpack-dev-serverをインストールしたもののローカル開発環境（localhost:8080）で作成したファイルを実行するとエラーが出ます。エラーを出さずにファイルの内容をブラウザで表示させるためにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

Tags: webpack

いつもお世話になっております。
下記の質問についてご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示を願います。

---

### 【質問の主旨】

[GitHub](https://github.com/echizenyayota/js_reciepe_v2_ch11-)にUPしているコードを`$ npm start` もしくは `$ npm run start`で実行するとターミナルの画面で下記のエラーが出ます。

```
> @ start /Users/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/firebase/js_reciepe_v2_ch11
> web-pack-dev-server --open

sh: web-pack-dev-server: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! @ start: `web-pack-dev-server --open`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/MYUSERNAME/.npm/_logs/2019-07-20T06_54_44_194Z-debug.log
```

このエラーを表示させずブラウザで`localhost:8080`にアクセスしたときコンソール画面に、

```
25
山田太郎です。
```

と表示させるためにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

### 【質問の補足】

エラーが発生するまでに行った作業はおおむね以下の1から4の通りです。

#### 1. webpack利用の準備

https://github.com/echizenyayota/js_reciepe_v2_ch11-/commit/43d7e0bbbe217bd5f8580a23f019785217cecf9e#diff-3ec03583f8eaec275cb2183db769ff47

#### 2. webpack-dev-serverのインストール

```
$ npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server
```

https://github.com/echizenyayota/js_reciepe_v2_ch11-/commit/b8f621b95087a8aacb0a32d5f6b897e7ca08ff08#diff-3ec03583f8eaec275cb2183db769ff47

#### 3. webpack.config.jsの編集

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/dist`,
    filename: 'main.js'
  },
   // deveServerプロパティを追記
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  }
};
```

https://github.com/echizenyayota/js_reciepe_v2_ch11-/blob/master/webpack.config.js

#### 4. package.jsonファイルの作成と編集

https://github.com/echizenyayota/js_reciepe_v2_ch11-/blob/master/package.json

以上の作業のうち、4番目のpackage.jsonに問題がありそうな気がしますが、質問の引用元となった[JavaScriptg逆引きレシピ第2版](https://www.shoeisha.co.jp/book/detail/9784798157573)のP.526で紹介されている、「コードを変更したときに自動的にバンドルを実行したい」を見ても、どのように修正すれば良いのか分かりません。

---

以上、よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

まず、 `package.json` に書かれているスクリプトについてですが、実行したいパッケージは **`web-pack-dev-server` ではなく、`webpack-dev-server`** なので<sup>[[1]](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserveropen)</sup>、ここを修正します。

---

次に、特に[プラグイン](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin)を使用しない状態で webpack を実行しただけでは、バンドルされた JavaScript ファイルが生成されるだけで、 HTML ファイルが自動的に作成されたり、 HTML ファイルにバンドルされた JavaScript ファイルが自動挿入されることはありません<sup>[[2]](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver)</sup> (実際には [serve-index](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-index) によりファイルの一覧が表示されます<sup>[[3]](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverserveindex)</sup>が、これはバンドルファイルを読み込みません)。

そのため、今回の場合、 **`dist` ディレクトリに `index.html` を作成しておく**必要があります。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>タイトル</title>
<script src="./main.js"></script>
```

Comment: supa さま。コメントありがとうございます。`"start": "webpack-dev-server --open",` に修正した上で`npm start` を実行すると`localhost:8080`のアドレスでブラウザが起動しました。また `dist` ディレクトリの下に、`index.html`を作成することで、`index.js`で記述した、`console.log(getTriangle(5, 10));` と`let p = new Person('山田太郎'); console.log(p.show());` の内容がブラウザのコンソール画面上で表示されることになりました。今後ともどうぞよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

```
-  "start": "web-pack-dev-server --open",
+  "start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
```

不要な `-` が原因な気がしました(^ ^)

Comment: 奥村健吾 さま。コメントありがとうございます。ご指摘のとおり`"start": "webpack-dev-server --open",` に修正した上で`npm start` を実行すると、
`> @ start /Users/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/js_reciepe_v2_ch11 > webpack-dev-server --open ...  Compiled successfully.` でという結果が返され、`localhost:8080/`でブラウザが立ち上がりました。今後ともどうぞよろしくお願いします。